# How do I change the time interval for Outlook 2007 appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

Currently the time interval for scheduling appointments using Outlook 2007 is 30 minutes. I'd like to change this interval to 15, 10 or even 5 minutes. Is that possible?

Comment: @Mike: Hello! Your question would be best served over on SuperUser.com. It will be moved there shortly and you should have a slew of answers yonder.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by highlighting the time and putting your own in or are you only interested in changing the default value?